# Making post pagination in wordpress works dynamically from php

Tags: php, wordpress

I creating a small plugin to add `<!--nextpage-->` shortcode under some requirements.

For example , my plugin will check if the user agent is a bot, if yes it will not add `<!--nextpage-->` and if not it will add it.

What I achieved so far is I created a function to check user agent :

```php
function test(){
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == ' Bot i want '){
    // here we dnt show <!--nextpage-->      
  } else {
      do_shortcode('<!--nextpage-->');      
  }
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode','test');
```

So when I add the short code in the post editor it work fine, but the only problem is it doesn't add the `<!--nextpage-->`, it doesn't get executed, and if I try other short codes like `[tweetme]` or other registred short codes they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To print out  into your html page, you shouldn't not call

```
 do_shortcode('<!--nextpage-->');
```

The above line will do nothing, since  is not a valid shortcode format in Wordpress, and as a result, do_shortcode cannot parse it.

A valid shortcode in wordpress need to be wrapped with [ ] brackets.

To achieve what you are trying to do (printing out '' when web crawler detected), you can just change your test function to:

```
function test(){
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == ' Bot i want '){
    // here we dnt show <!--nextpage-->      
  } else {
     echo '<!--nextpage-->';      
  }
}
```

Also, you can have a look at do_shortcode function documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: The result here will print <!--nextpage--> as a comment into html code , and wordpress will not proccess the code , please any other idea ! because seems not to work

Comment: How do you know Wordpress will not process the code if it is a printing command to print <!--nextpage--> into html code ? Are you kidding ?

Comment: do you ever tried <!--nextpage--> before?
its being proceeded before post loading , u can try it now, and im not kidding